# How to conditionally select a node in XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd

The XSD schema I am working with, calls for either an international or domestic address:

```
"/mns:PhysicalAddress/mns:DomesticAddress/mns:City"
```

or

```
"/mns:PhysicalAddress/mns:InternationalAddress/mns:City"
```

It is being used as a parameter in a Java method as in `XMLUtils.BuildField(Document doc, String xpath)`.

I know I can go straight to the Java object that created that `doc` and use the auto-generated beans to query elements, but I prefer remaining within the concise realm of XPath. Is this possible?

If so, how do I write an XPath expression selects `mns:City` regardless of whether it is international or domestic address?

Note: This in **Java**, not Javascript, HTML or XSLT, so I don't think `<xsl:if>` is relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with finding all Cities that have either parent:

```
//mns:City[(parent::mns:DomesticAddress|parent::mns:InternationalAddress)]
```

If you need to also ensure that the address is in the physical address:

```
//mns:City[(parent::mns:DomesticAddress|parent::mns:InternationalAddress)[parent::mns:PhysicalAddress]]
```

Alternatively, instead of reversing the hierarchy, you do a `*` and check the name:

```
/mns:PhysicalAddress/*[name()="mns:DomesticAddress" or name()="mns:InternationalAddress"]/mns:City
```

Comment: Thank you! Does the expression you put there comes instead of the single `/mns:City` in my original `xpath`? Or is it standlone? I have never seen this "reverse hierarchy" before, that's why I am asking. +1 for now and I will accept once I get it tested.

Comment: It is standalone (ie would completely replace your current xpath). I do not believe the reverse hierarchy is common. I have only seen it used for this type of scenario where you need to do a sort of `or` on a node.

Comment: Okay, figured out how to go down the hierarchy - see last example.

Answer (score 2):

Depending in the precise structure of your XML,

```
/mns:PhysicalAddress/*/mns:City
```

may be enough, if that pulls in too much then the clearest option is probably just to use the two alternatives you already have, separated by a `|`:

```
/mns:PhysicalAddress/mns:DomesticAddress/mns:City | /mns:PhysicalAddress/mns:InternationalAddress/mns:City
```

Or slightly more concise but (in my opinion) less clear:

```
/mns:PhysicalAddress/*[self::mns:DomesticAddress | self::mns:InternationalAddress]/mns:City
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks more concise than the previous suggestion, I like it. By *"just use the two alternatives you already have, separated by a |"*, do you mean `"/mns:PhysicalAddress/mns:DomesticAddress|mns:InternationalAddress/mns:City"`?

Comment: @WinWin If you have XPath 2.0 then you can do `/mns:PhysicalAddress/(mns:DomesticAddress|mns:InternationalAddress)/mns:City`, but if you're restricted to 1.0 then you'll have to union the whole paths (or do a trick with the `self::` axis), I've edited the answer with an example.